# Permission to Write Apex Code

Tags: apex, permissions

What permission is needed to write apex code?  I trying to determine what permission I should grant my vendor in our developer sandbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Author Apex" under "Administrative Permissions" for the associated profile of the user.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

They need the **Author Apex** permission. Ticking this box will result in them being assigned a lot of other permissions as well though.

Granting **Author Apex** permission also gives the user the following permissions:

- Modify All Data
- View Setup and Configuration

Granting **Modify All Data** also gives the user the following permissions:

- Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All on all standard and custom objects
- Edit Events
- Edit Tasks
- Manage Public List Views
- Manage Public Templates
- Run Reports
- Transfer Record
- View Setup and Configuration
- Manage Public Documents
- Import Leads
- Transfer Leads
- View All Data
- Use Team Reassignment Wizards
- Manage Categories
- Convert Leads
- Import Solutions
- Create and Set Up Communities
- Connect Organization to Environment Hub
- Manage Reports in Public Folders
- Manage Dashboards in Public Folders
- Delete Topics
- Assign Topics
- Create Topics
- Edit Topics